# Fundamental Description Of Algebras Over The Monad $PP^{op}:\text{Set}\to\text{Set}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, topos-theory, monads

$
\newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon}
\newcommand{\op}{^\text{op}}
\newcommand{\id}{\text{id}}
\newcommand{\set}{\text{Set}}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
$Can someone help me to understand how algebras over the monad $T:=PP\op$, with $P:\set\op\to\set$ being the powerset functor taking maps to inverse images, look like?  Note that this is not a duplicate of [understanding the algebras of the powerset monad](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3008911/algebras-of-the-powerset-monad), which concerns the monad $P':\set\to\set$ which takes maps to direct images.  This question was also flagged as duplicate of [what are the algebras of the double powerset monad](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94741/what-are-the-algebras-of-the-double-powerset-monad), which is very close, although I am more interested in sets than in Boolean algebras.

This is what I got so far:

Let $P:\set\op\to\set$ be the powerset functor with left adjoint $P\op:\set\to\set\op$ where the unit $\eta(U):U\to PP\op U$ maps $x\in U$ to the set $\{X\subseteq U:x\in X\}$ and the counit $\eps$ is just the corresponding arrow in the opposite category.  So we can construct a monad $T:=PP\op$ from this adjoint pair as usual with $\mu(U):TTU\to TU$ defined via $$TTU=PP\op PP\op U\xra{P\eps(P\op U)} PP\op U=TU$$ and I wonder how the algebras over this monad look like.

Recall that an algebra over $U$ is a map $a:TU\to U$ such that

1. $U\xra{\eta(U)}TU\xra{a} U=\id(U)$ and
2. $TTU\xra{\mu(U)}TU\xra{a}U=TTU\xra{T(a)}TU\xra{a}U$.

(1.) is relatively straight forward, the set of all $X$ containing $x$ must be mapped back to $x$ by $a$.

For (2.), note is that both, $\mu(U)$ and $T(a)$, are of the shape $Pf$ for some $f:P\op U\to P\op TU$, so given some $W\in TTU$, they return all $X\in P\op U$ such that $f(X)\in W$.  This relation can further simplified by noting that if $a$ already satisfies (1.), $f$ is in both cases injective.  For $\mu(U)$ we have $f_0:=e(P\op U)$ mapping $X$ to the principal filter containing all $Y\in TU$ with $X\in Y$, which is clearly injective, and for $T(a)$ we have $f_1:=P\op(a)$ which maps $X$ to the set of $Y$ with $a(Y)\in X$, which is also injective since $\eta(U)$ is injective and $a$ satisfies (1.).  Let $W_i$ be the image of $P\op U$ under $f_i$ and let $Y_{0\cap 1}$ be the inverse image of $W_0\cap W_1$.

So $a$ is only allowed to care for elements in $Y_{0\cap 1}$, since the others can be independently added or removed under $f_0$ and $f_1$ by changing $W$ accordingly.

We can see that $W_0$ is what I call a disjoint free antichain, for $Z_0\neq Z'_0\in W_0$, let's say $Z_0$ is the principal filter of $X$ and $Z'_0$ the principal filter of $X'$, neither $Z_0\subset Z'_0$ nor $Z'_0\subset Z_0$ nor $Z_0\cap Z'_0=\emptyset$ since only $Z_0$ contains $\{X\}$, only $Z'_0$ contains $\{X'\}$ and both contain $\{X,X'\}$.  On the other hand, if $X\subset X'$, clearly $f_1(X)\subseteq f_1(X')$ and by (1.) also $f_1(X)\subset f_1(X')$, a contradiction.  Similar with $X\cap X'=\emptyset$, so it follows that $Y_{0\cap 1}$ must inherit the disjoint free antichain property from $W_0$.

But from (1.) we can also see that if $x,x'\in U$ with $x\neq x'$, we must have $X,X'\in Y_{0\cap 1}$ such that $X$ contains $x$ but not $x'$ and $X'$ contains $x'$ but not $x$, otherwise $\eta(U)x\cap Y_{0\cap 1}=\eta(U)x'\cap Y_{0\cap 1}$ and $a$ would not be able to differentiate the two sets.

So all in all we have this strange system of disjoint free antichains which can differentiate between all elements.  I don't know if there is a special name for this property.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  It's a similar question, but it asks for equivalence with the category of complete atomic Boolean algebras, which is equivalent to $\text{Set}$, while I'm asking how the algebras look like in $\text{Set}$.

Comment: I nominate this for reopening. It's unfortunate it was closed by the community bot, which is presumably blind to subtle differences in the question. Maybe change the title?

Comment: Thanks for the nomination!  Do you have an idea for a better title?  I think I can answer this question later, I put some more thought into it in the meantime...

Comment: You’re using $\mu$ for multiple different things. I recommend using $\eta$ for the unit $1\implies PP$

Comment: Yes, that's a typo, should be $\eta$ for the unit, I'm in the process of rewriting the question, thanks for the comment!

Comment: Hey, I hope it's better now!

Comment: Doesn't the well-known fact that $P$ is monadic just imply that any $P P^{op}$-algebra is isomorphic to $PX$ for some $X$, with the algebra structure being $P \eta_X : P^3 X \to P X$?

Comment: Yes.  It seems that for the finite case, the structure I describe is only realizable if $n$ is a power of $2$ and also every algebra *looks* like the function mapping $Y$ to "set" $x$ of "elements" $x^*$ such that the principal filter of $x^*$ is contained in $Y$.